# Using cnn models trained on different datasets

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am having 3 different datasets, 3 of them were all blood smear image stained with the same chemical substance. Blood smear images are images that capture your blood, include Red, White blood cells inside.

The first dataset contain 2 classes : normal vs blood cancer
The second dataset contain 2 classes: normal vs blood infection
The third dataset contain 2 classes: normal vs sickle cell disease

So, what i want to do is : when i input a blood smear image, the AI system will tell me whether it was : normal , or blood cancer or blood infection or sickle cell disease (4 classes classification task)

What should i do?

Should i mix these 3 datasets and train only 1 model to detect 4 classes ?

Or should i train 3 different models and them combine them? If yes, what method should i use to combine?

Update : i searched for a while. Can this task called "Learning without forgetting?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the data.

You may use three different models and make three binary predictions on each image. So you get a vote (probability) for each x vs. normal. If binary classifications are accurate, this should deliver okay results. But you kind of get a cummulated missclassification or error in this case.

If you can afford, you can train a four class model and compare the test error to the series of binary classifications. I understand that you already have three models. So training another one may be not too expensive.

If ONLY one of the classes can occur, a four class model might be the way to go. If in fact two (or more) classes can occur jointly, a series of binary classifications would make sense.

Comment: i understood, at the moment only one class can occur at a time. However, is there any technical term for 'mixing 4 datasets and train only 1 model' ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with technical term... it is simply a model with four instead of two classes. The output layer has dimension 4 in this case. Training etc is pretty much the same (model architecture may be little different but otherwise no big changes).

Comment: Also note that you may profit from using a pretrained model and learn on top of it.

Comment: This is an example for a Keras multiclass image classification built on a pretrained model https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52276/improve-accuracy-of-keras-multiclass-image-classification-with-pretrained-vgg16

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter said it is totally data dependent. If the images of the 4 classes, namely  normal ,blood cancer ,blood infection ,sickle cell disease are easily distinguishable with your naked eyes and there is no scope of confusion among all the classes then you should simply go for 1 model which gives out probabilities  of all the 4 classes(as mentioned by @maxi marufo). If there is confusion between classes and the images are NOT distinguishable with naked eyes or there is a lot of scope of confusion between the classes then you should use 3 different models but then you'll need. You simply get the predicted probabilities from all the 3 models suppose p1(normal) and p1(c1), p2(normal) and p2(c2), p3(normal) and p3(c3). Now you can average(p1(normal),p2(normal),p3(normal)) and the use a softmax for p(normal), p1(c1), p2(c2), p3(c3) . Out of multiple ways you could try, the above could be one.

Comment: What do you mean confusion ? You mean the logical connection between classes ?

Comment: By confusion i mean, not being able to identify the differences between the classes easily by naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multiclass classification problem. You can train just one model, with the final layer being a full connected (dense) layer of 4 units (i.e. output dimension) and softmax activation function.

Comment: Update : i searched for a while. Can this task similar to "Learning without forgetting?"

Comment: I searched for "Larning without forgetting", and it's about retraining a model. You can either train a model from zero with some intitialization, or used a pretrained one. In any case, your solution would need a model with the final layer being a full connected layer of 4 units and softmax activation function.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation